# Use of "considered" in "May I be considered"

Tags: word-usage

Someone was giving something away for free and I asked the below...

> Hello Kristian, may I be considered please, I can collect tonight after work

I am asking for clarification as I was told I used the word "considered" in the wrong context.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Considered sounds like a correct word to use. You want the item someone has, and you want that person to consider giving it to you. It may not be the vert *best* word to use in this sentence, but it is not wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your use of 'considered' is absolutely fine. Your sentence sounds a little formal ... even though it is a context where formality is appropriate.

The only problem I see is punctuation. Technically you have three sentences which you have joined with commas. To sound a bit more natural, and to correct the punctuation, you could say:

> Hello Kristian. I'd very much like to be considered for [the item]. I'm available after work tonight to pick it up, if that's convenient for you.

Comment: Also, as you show by changing it to "pick it up", "collect" is usually a transitive verb and requires a direct object. (I agree with you that "pick it up" sounds better than "collect it", also.)

Comment: You're correct. I missed the missing 'it' after 'collect'.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

I'll say for American English, "consider" might not be wrong per se, but it definitely sounds odd to me. From dictionary.com:

> consider - to think carefully about, especially in order to make a decision; contemplate; reflect on

If Kristian is giving something away for free, they're probably not going to be making a list of pros and cons for everyone that wants it. They'll probably just give it to the first person that asks. Consider would make more sense in a situation where different factors need to be weighed, such as an open job position or buying a house.

Collect also might not be wrong, but sounds off because it's not used as commonly in this situation. Collect also should be used with a grammatical object e.g. "I can collect **it**..."  We'd more likely use the verb "to pick-up".

In a situation like this, the main thing we'd ask is, "is the item still available?"
It'd sound much more natural to just say something like:

> Hello Kristian, is [the item] still available? I could pick it up
>   tonight after work.

With [the item] replaced with whatever it is you're asking about

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the assistance.